# How do I perform a wildcard search of a bytes hex value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io, wildcard

I'm currently trying to write a model import script for blender and the vertex coordinates within the file I need to parse through are preceded by the 8 bit header 68 * 80 04, with the decimal value of whatever "*" is identifying the number of vertices. Given that the header isn't entirely consistent throughout the file I was wondering  what methods are there to perform a wildcard search of a bytes hexadecimal representation once it's read in?

Answer (score 1):

You could use regular expressions:

```
import re

with open('filename', 'rb') as file:
    bs = file.read()

matches = re.findall(b'\x68.\x80\x04', bs)
```

Comment: Excellent, I'll give it a try.